# Why is the following function not o(h)?

Tags: limits, poisson-process

Given that a function is $o(h)$ if

\begin{equation}
  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}=0\\
\end{equation}

Why is $P(N(h)>0) \neq o(h)$ (where $N(h)$ is a Poisson process) ?

**My attempt**

\begin{equation}
  P(N(h)>(k=0)) = 1-P(N(h)=0) = 1 - \frac {e^{-\lambda h}(\lambda h)^k}{k!}\\
\end{equation}

which gives
\begin{equation}
  P(N(h)>(k=0)) = 1 - \frac {e^{-\lambda h}(1)}{1}\\
\end{equation}

and then dividing by h,

\begin{equation}
  P(N(h)>(k=0)) =  \frac {1 -e^{-\lambda h}}{h}\\
\end{equation}

If I were to take $\lim_{h \to 0}$, wouldn't the numerator essentially be $1-1=0$? How should I approach this?

Comment: As you take $h \to 0$, BOTH numerator and denominator are approaching $0$ (indeterminate form). So you still need to compute the limit using (say)  L'Hospital etc.. To get the limit as $-\lambda$.

Comment: Ah, so if I take the first derivative, I would get $f'(h)=\lambda$ and since $f(0) \neq f'(0)=\lambda$, therefore this is not $o(h)$. Is the correct?

Comment: Pretty much, except that $f'(0)=-\lambda$ (assuming that your $f(h)=1-e^{\lambda h})$.

Comment: Opps. Yeah, forgotten about that negative sign. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: In the question and many of the comments, wherever there is a $e^{\lambda h}$ it should have $e^{-\lambda h}$.  The derivative of $f(h)=1-e^{-\lambda h}$ is $\lambda e^{-\lambda h}$, and not its negative.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for pointing out, I've edit it now. I missed out the negative sign in the original equations. That's why I got $f'(0)=\lambda$ in the first place from "muscle memory". Nonetheless, everything else discussed is still accurate.